# Fork wait and pipe in C

Tags: c, pipe, fork

I have this assignment where we are supposed to create a specific amount of child processes, lets say 3, and make the parent wait for each child to finish. Also we're supposed to have a pipe that all processes write to so that once the parent is done waiting, it would use the pipe's to output the sum of all the children's results.

This is my code so far but it seems that `wait(NULL)` isn't working as expected. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    pid_t child = fork();
    if (child > 0) {
      printf("Child %d created\n", child);
      wait(NULL);
      printf("Child %d terminated\n", child);
    }
  }

  printf("Parent terminated\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the loop, the first child created will continue on to the next iteration and call 'fork' unless you 'break'

Comment: Also, every child created (more than 3) is going to write "Parent terminated".  In addition, if you redirect or pipe the output of your program so that it is not line buffered, you'll see what you may consider odd behavior.  You probably want to add an else clause: `if(child > ) {...} else { _exit(0); }`

Comment: You have made the parent process wait as soon as it creates its first child process. furthermore, the child process will continue to create its own children (since it was forked in the middle of a loop) and so on. I smell a recursion. Is that what you were asked for? Did they specify what the child processes were supposed to do?

Comment: Interesting. So moving `wait(NULL)` outside the loop fixed it but as you guys said, it seems that I get more than 3 children.
What am I doing wrong here? I need to fork 3 processes from the parent but not from the children. How do I stop the recursion?

Comment: @WilliamPursell Please check my comment.

Comment: The child needs to exit before it calls `fork`.  Add an `else` clause that exits.

Comment: If you're meant to use a pipe, you need to use the `pipe()` system call.  If the children are meant to write data to the parent, the child process needs to do some writing, presumably on the pipe.  You've not even attempted any of that.  Are you going to have one pipe shared between children or one pipe per child.  Both designs are possible; one pipe is sufficient here as long as you write the result in a small enough chunk (less than 64 KiB).  You do need to think about how the parent will know the boundaries between what each child wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's better to first run all child processes and then wait for all of them, instead of waiting for each one sequentially.

In addition, the child processes should exit immediately and not keep running the forked code.

Thirdly, you must pay attention and wait for all children after the loop, and not only for the first one that terminates:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    pid_t child = fork();
    if (child > 0) {
      printf("Child %d created\n", child);
    }
    else if (child == 0) {
      printf("In child %d. Bye bye\n", i);
      return 0; // exit the child process
    }
  }

  while (wait(NULL) > 0); // wait for all child processes

  printf("Parent terminated\n");
  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

The code above is just an improvement to the example given in the question. In order to implement the pipe of information from the child processes to the parent, a pipe can be created (using `pipe()`) and the write-end file descriptor would be accessible from child processes.

[Here's](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-demonstrate-fork-and-pipe/) a good example to do so.

Comment: I don't see the pipe, nor the summing, mentioned in the question.  You've picked on some important points, but not all of them.

Comment: Hey thanks, you're right. I tried to take the code example and improve it. There was no code regarding the pip of information. This could be done using creating a pipe (using `pipe()`) in the parent process, the write-end file descriptor will be accessible to the child processes and they could write information into the pipe. I'll add link to an example.